missing ; in mysql
CREATE TABLE `hmi_to_mes1` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL,
  `Note` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db_5300`.`hmi_to_mes_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `hmi_to_mes` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CALL `db_5300`.align_hmi_to_mes1()
END;

in mine mySql code it says me "missing ;" on the last row END;
I tryed some ; in different positions but it didn't resolved anything

The call statement needs to be terminated. Also since there is only 1 statement you don't need the begin and end statements but if you want them you may need to set delimiters, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/stored-programs-defining.html

So i can remove BEGIN and END?

Yes, you can remove BEGIN_END for your particular case.

you should end this statement with semicolon(;),then you won't get that error.
BEGIN
CALL db_5300.align_hmi_to_mes1();
